# ClearCase: how to generate a patch (unified diff) file from an activity?

Tags: diff, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is it possible to generate an patch file from the changeset of a UCM Activity in ClearCase?

I can generate the list of changes this way:
     cleartool lsactivity -l activity:my_activity_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main  approach is list all the files within an activity, and use [`cleartool diff -pred -diff_format`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-10) in order to generate a diff.

With the `-diff_format` option, you would get headers and differences in the same style as the UNIX and Linux diff utility.

But that would require some scripting, as I mentioned in "[Change set predecessor using cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034423/6309)".

Comment: Just another trivial version control task that is die hard to do in ClearCase. There are just 6 files, I'll do it by hand. Thanks,  @VonC. IBM should pay you a salary for answering questions about their terrible version control system. I'll accept your answer, but change if someone posts a functioning script here.